# Turtle pen too blurry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I'm making a platformer game with python turtle, the game not built for high graphics any way, the rendering created with pen, but I still want a way to make the pen less pixelated,
I tried a lot of things like using tkinter root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2.0) and ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
but it just don't work on the turtle pen  graphics.

example:

```
from turtle import *
wn = Screen()
wn.colormode(255)

pen = Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.ht()
pen.pu()
pen.pensize(15)
pen.pencolor(0, 255, 255)
pen.setpos(-150, -50)
pen.pd()
pen.setpos(150, 50)

wn.mainloop()
```

So that code draws a diagonal line, but as you can see it is too pixelated, and I guess it has resolution limit (not sure):
[screen shot from the code up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfNyR.png)

[screen shot of the life bar from my own game when using 1920x1080 resolution and it still seems like 720p not anti aliased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpBMt.png)

so if you know any way to do it, really thanks, if you can't find a way to do it through turtle or tkinter, or any other trusted module, I don't even care if I have to edit turtle for the solution.

Comment: create a [example]